# Overloaded Method calling in Java

Tags: java, methods

Let's say I have 2 methods as such:

```
1    public int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

2    public double sum(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
```

If I call sum, like so: `sum(2, 3)`
The first method will be executed

If I call sum, like so: `sum(2.5,3.5)`The second method is executed

However, if I call sum like such: `sum(2.5,3)`, the second method is executed, but not the first, why is that?

Also, would this also be the case if sum was called as such: `sum(3,2.5)`?

Comment: Yes because the compiler will promote the literal  2 (or 3) to a double.

Comment: You can also put a lowercase `d` on the end of integers to cast them to doubles, such as `1d` ... just an odd thing to share with you

Comment: @ThisClark +1, I didn't know that until now! Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler will make the int into a double, calling the second method It is because, an int can be typecasted into a double, but not vice versa.

This will apply for all the primitive types going to the right. **You can't go to the left, unless you explicitly typecast, which you aren't doing.** If you wanted the first method to be executed, you could just typecast into an int, so that it doesn't widen into a double. Java is very specific about these things:

SO, in conclusion, when you call the method **without typecasting the int,** doing this:

```
 sum(int, double);
```

is actually translating to this:

```
 sum(double, double);
```

and to avoid this, you must typecast your int as an int.

Answer (score 2):

Because, **integer**s can be as **floating-point** numbers in Math.
So, `sum(3,2.5)` - here worth method signature is `sum(double, double)`!